# Question concerning Boolean Algebra of pairs

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I am reading a book "Boolean Algebra" by R.L. Goodstein.

In section 2.19 of the chapter "Self dual system of axioms", I am not able to comprehend what the author is trying to say in the first line of the very section.

It says,
"If we select *the subset of pairs $(A, A^c) $ from the set of pairs $(A, B) $* $\dots $".

What is meant by "*the subset of pairs $(A, A^c) $ from the set of pairs $(A, B)$.*" ?

Here is the picture.

[image]

A detailed explanation that what is meant by the author here would be helpful.

Comment: You could probably copy the sentence instead of linking a picture. Also, without more context it's going to be hard to answer your question for someone who does not have the book.

Comment: For your bounty on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282908), your doubts could be better cleared if you tell what they are exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pairs $(A,B)$ have the property that $B=A^c$; others don't. The set of pairs of the form $(A,A^c)$ forms a subset of the set of *all* pairs. Put another way, we have two sets of pairs in question:

- The set of all pairs.
- The set of pairs where the second coordinate is the complement of the first coordinate.

The point is that the latter is a subset of the former.

Comment: What is the symbol we use to represent a subset of a pairs ?

Comment: @AdityaRaj There's no special symbol - if $X$ is the set of all pairs and $Y$ is the set of special pairs (= pairs where the two coordinates are each others' complements), we write "$Y\subseteq X$" as usual.